# Could not deduce (Floating a) arising from a use of `pi'

Tags: haskell

`circleArea` is  function to calculate the area of a circle given the radius `r`:

```
circleArea r = r^2 * pi
```

However, adding the type signature `circleArea :: Num a => a -> a` causes this error:

```
* Could not deduce (Floating a) arising from a use of `pi'
  from the context: Num a
    bound by the type signature for:
               circleArea :: forall a. Num a => a -> a
  Possible fix:
    add (Floating a) to the context of
      the type signature for:
        circleArea :: forall a. Num a => a -> a
* In the second argument of `(*)', namely `pi'
  In the expression: r * r * pi
  In an equation for `circleArea': circleArea r = r * r * pi
```

Using `circleArea :: Floating a => a -> a`, as suggested, resolves the issue.

I'm running this on [repl.it](https://repl.it).

Why isn't `Num` a valid typeclass here? `pi` has a type of `Floating a -> a`, isn't `pi` a `Num` as well?

Comment: Because `pi` has type `Floating a => a`. It would be odd to have a `circleArea 2` that is an `Int`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I don't get that. ```Num``` encompasses more than just ```Int```, doesn't it?

Comment: @Harith that's exactly the problem - `Num` is wider than `Floating`. Your type signature says your function works for all types in `Num`, yet the implementation only works for those in `Floating`, hence there's a mismatch.

Comment: @Harith: if you specify `circleArea :: Num a => a -> a`, you say that for *any* `a`, that will work, so for `Float`s, `Int`s, `Double`s, `Integer`s, etc.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Ahh, so I'm telling Haskell it's supposed to work for *all* those types. I can see what the problem would be. Thanks. It was my bad knowledge of what a typeclass was.

Comment: @Willem would ```(Num a, Floating b) => a -> b``` be a better choice?

Comment: @Harith: that is not possible with the current implementation, since `r` and the output type are here have to be the same type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this happens is because `pi` has type [**`pi :: Floating a => a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:pi). When you multiply two items, then the two operands as well as the result all have the same type, since `(*)` has type [**`(*) :: Num a => a -> a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-42-).

This thus means that `r^2` should have the same type as `pi` and thus as `r^2 * pi`. Since `pi` can take any type as long as it is a `Floating` type, this thus means that `r^2` should be `Floating` as well, and since `(^)` has type [**`(^) :: (Num a, Integral b) => a -> b -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-94-), it thus means that `r` has the same type as `r^2`, and therefore `r` also has to be a `Floating` type. This thus means that both `r` and `r^2 * pi` have as type `Floating`.

This also makes sense. It would be rather odd that we could have an `Int` as result, since we multiply with something that is clearly not integral.